# Which of these statements about $2 \times 2$ real matrices $A$ such that $A^5 = I$ are true?

Tags: linear-algebra

> There exists a $2 \times  2$ real matrix $A$ such that $A^5 = I$.
>
> **a)** $A$ must be identity.
>
> **b)** $A$ must be similar to an element of $SO(2)$ .
>
> **c)** $A$ must be diagonalisable.

I have checked that minimal polynomial must divide $(x^5-1)=(x-1)(x^4+\dots+1)$ so it must be  $x-1$ so $A=I$, and of course diagonalizable so **a** and **c** are correct options, but I am not sure about **b**.

Comment: If $\zeta = a + bi$ is a fifth root of unity in $\mathbb C$, try $A = \left(\begin{matrix}a & b \\ -b & a \end{matrix}\right)$.

Comment: @Bicycle Theif: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: @Bicycle Theif: Note that although $A=I$ is *one* solution, you did not show that it is the *only* solution (in fact there are others, as Charles points out). In order for statement **a** to be true, the identity matrix would have to be the *only* $2\times 2$ real matrix satisfying $A^5=I$.

Comment: @Bicycle Theif: Lastly, please make the titles of your posts actual *questions*, not just the first introductory line of your post, so that people can understand what you are asking from looking at the front page.

Comment: other factor is of degree 4 and irreducible over real and contribute complex roots of unity, so I concluded $x-1$ must be minimal polynomial.

Comment: @BicycleTheif: Just because no real *numbers* satisfy the polynomial $x^4 + \dotsb + 1$, it does not follow that no real *matrices* satisfy this polynomial.

Comment: Then I must need actual reasons or answers, help me.

Comment: The degree 4 polynomial you mentioned is not irreducible.  It is $(x^2-2\cos(2\pi/5)x+1)(x^2-2\cos(4\pi/5)x+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a matrix that rotates by 72 degrees. I.e. the matrix A so that Ax has rotated the vector x by 72 degrees about the origin. We then $A^5 = I.$

a) and c) are false for this matrix.

b) is true however. So the question is then is b) always true?